# visNetwork not displaying in panel div

Tags: html, r, shiny, graph-visualization, visnetwork

I have started to use shinyLP to make html elements and also make network diagrams using visNetwork. I noticed that visNetwork displays fine when placed in either a well panel or no panel at all. However, it does not display when placed in a panel div, either with shinyLP or through raw HTML. Just to be brief, I am only showing the code differences between not being in a panel and being in a panel div. **Does anyone know of a way to make visNetwork appear in this specific container type?** I want to use this container type because I want to keep my CSS the way it is and not change things just for this one container. Anyone know the cause of this issue?

## This works when visNetworkOutput is not in a panel

```
library(shinyLP)
library(visNetwork)

ui <- fluidPage(

visNetworkOutput("network")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
        nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
        edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

        visNetwork(nodes, edges)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This fails to display when visNetworkOutput is in a panel

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    panel_div("default", "", visNetworkOutput("network"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
        # minimal example
        nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
        edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

        visNetwork(nodes, edges)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting with `panel_div()`? If you look at the documentation you will see: `panel_div(class_type, panel_title, content)` that you try to pass your network as the `content` parameter, which is described as: "a[n] object of class character, indicating text content". So your output will be converted to type character and it will not be displayed,...

Comment: No, it is just a bug I think :). But it could well be that it was not tested - i.e. not in the test matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in `shinyJS` version 1.1.0. I found a (awkward) workaround and posted it as a bug in `htmlwidgets` and Joe Cheng saw it and give me a fix it in like 10 minutes. Awesome...

Here is the code with a better workaround (a new definition of `pandel_div`):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyLP)
library(visNetwork)

# override the currently broken definition in shinyLP version 1.1.0
panel_div <- function(class_type, panel_title, content) {
  div(class = sprintf("panel panel-%s", class_type),
      div(class = "panel-heading",
          h3(class = "panel-title", panel_title)
      ),
      div(class = "panel-body", content)
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  panel_div("default", "panel1",visNetworkOutput("network")  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({ 
    # minimal network
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
    visNetwork(nodes,edges) 
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is what that looks like:

[image]

**update:** Tried with another `htmlwidget` package (`sigma`) and got the same behavior. So filing this as an `htmlwidget` bug: [panel_div htmlwidget issue](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/276)

**update:** JC identified it as a `shinyJS` bug. Changed my solution above to reflect his suggestion.

Comment: I tried it out this morning at work and it worked like a charm! Thanks for the quick and complete answer.